# Could not load type 'System.Reflection.Metadata.ISignatureTypeProvider from assembly System.Reflection.Metadata

Tags: c#, .net-core, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis, project.json

I'm currently trying to experiment with the Roslyn Workspaces API on OSX and keep running into the following exception when calling `CreateRoslynWorkspace`:

> "Could not load type 'System.Reflection.Metadata.ISignatureTypeProvider`1' from assembly 'System.Reflection.Metadata, Version=1.4.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'."

Is anyone else able to shed some light as to what could be causing this?

Here is the code I am using:

```
public static class Class1
{
    public static IEnumerable<Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspace> Create(string projectPath)
    {
        var builder = new ProjectContextBuilder().WithProjectDirectory(projectPath);

        return builder.BuildAllTargets().Select(context => context.CreateRoslynWorkspace());
    }

    public static void GetProject()
    {
        // Entry point
        var path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "/src/DemoLib/project.json";
        var result = Create(path).ToList();
    }
}
```

and this is the project.json I am using

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "buildOptions": {
    "debugType": "portable"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp": "2.0.0-rc2",
    "Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Features": "2.0.0-rc2",
    "Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces": "2.0.0-rc2",
    "Microsoft.DotNet.ProjectModel": "1.0.0-rc3-1-003177",
    "Microsoft.DotNet.ProjectModel.Loader": "1.0.0-preview2-1-003177",
    "Microsoft.DotNet.ProjectModel.Workspaces": "1.0.0-preview2-1-003177"
  },
    "frameworks": {
      "netcoreapp1.1": {
        "imports": [ "portable-net45+win8" ]
      }
    }
}
```

Here is the entire stack trace too:

> "   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module)\n   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.get_DefinedTypes()\n   at System.Composition.Hosting.ContainerConfiguration.b__0(Assembly a)\n   at System.Linq.Enumerable.d__159`2.MoveNext()\n   at System.Composition.TypedParts.TypedPartExportDescriptorProvider..ctor(IEnumerable`1 types, AttributedModelProvider attributeContext)\n   at System.Composition.Hosting.ContainerConfiguration.CreateContainer()\n   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Host.Mef.MefHostServices.Create(IEnumerable`1 assemblies)\n   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Host.Mef.MefHostServices.get_DefaultHost()\n   at Microsoft.DotNet.ProjectModel.Workspaces.ProjectJsonWorkspace..ctor(ProjectContext context)\n   at Microsoft.DotNet.ProjectModel.Workspaces.WorkspaceProjectContextExtensions.CreateRoslynWorkspace(ProjectContext context)\n   at ClassLibrary.Class1.<>c.<Create>b__0_0(ProjectContext context) in /Users/personal/Dev/RoslynWorkspace2/src/Lib/Library.cs:line 16\n   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()\n   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)\n   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)\n   at ClassLibrary.Class1.GetProject() in /Users/personal/Dev/RoslynWorkspace2/src/Lib/Library.cs:line 21\n   at WebAPIApplication.Controllers.ValuesController.Get() in /Users/personal/Dev/RoslynWorkspace2/src/WebAPIApplication/Controllers/ValuesController.cs:line 13\n   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.d__28.MoveNext()"

Comment: Hi, Joseph, have you resolved this issue?

Comment: Yes I did, it turns out it was an issue in one of the packages, I rolled back to a previous version and the problem went away.

Answer (score -1):

Add "System.Reflection.Metadata" as dependency to the project.json.